# backup asus recovery partition to external drive

Tags: backup, recovery

I cloned the ~20 GB ASUS recovery partition of my ASUS laptop to an external SSD. How do I make this bootable so that I can run recovery from my external drive? Is this possible?

The whole goal was to backup the recovery partition so, if something happens to the laptop SSD, I can restore the laptop to factory settings from an external backup. I just wasn't sure if I need to clone the whole disk instead of just the ASUS partition for this to be possible.

Comment: Why do you want to restore the recovery partition?  It's not required and likely would restore a version other than the Windows version you are currently running.  Why don't you just clone the entire SSD?

Comment: I want the ASUS programs that came with the new laptop, thus my keeping of the recovery partition. I don't have enough space on my external SSD to clone the whole disk.

Comment: Are you aware you can download every single one of those programs directly from ASUS on their website? You are going to have to provide us with more information on HOW you cloned the partition to a removable drive.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. I just used Macrium Reflect to clone the ASUS recovery partition from my internal 1 TB SSD to my external 480 GB SSD.